# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select from ReceiveNote if fromloc = 1 then print Factory else have to print Other

```
SELECT PurDate,
case ReceiveNote.FromLOC
when ReceiveNote.FromLOC = '1' THEN 'Factory'
when ReceiveNote.FromLOC = '2' THEN 'Other'
else ''
end as FromLOC FROM tbl1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already specified field after `CASE` word. No need to specify it again.

```
SELECT PurDate,
       CASE ReceiveNote.FromLOC
            WHEN '1' THEN 'Factory'
            WHEN '2' THEN 'Other'
            ELSE ''
       END AS FromLOC 
  FROM tbl1
```

And [here is documentation on CASE for tsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PurDate,
case when ReceiveNote.FromLOC = '1' THEN 'Factory'
when ReceiveNote.FromLOC = '2' THEN 'Other'
else ''
end as FromLOC FROM tbl1
```